# Split survey text cell in multiple (unique and binary) columns

Tags: r, survey

I have a survey database at user level, one of the fields has several multiple choices that the user has selected. Example

`col1 | col2
 ID1  | a, b, c
 ID2  | c, f
 ID3  | g, k, z`

I want to reshape the file as follows using R:

`col1| col2(a)| col3(b)| col4(c)| col5(f)| col6(g)| col7(k)| col8(z)** 
ID1  | 1      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0 
ID2  | 0      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 0      | 0      | 0 
ID3  | 0      | 0      | 0      | 0      | 1      | 1      | 1`

please note: I don't know how many distinct values are existing in the original multiple choice field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is `mtabuate` after splitting the 'col2' by `,`

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1], mtabulate(strsplit(df1$col2, ", ")))
```